# Get command PID and send to another

Tags: process, pid

I wanted to know if I can execute a command from the terminal and right after the command started I send its PID to another command to be monitored.

I need to do something like this,

```
dd if=/path/of/file of=/path/of/destination
```

And then I need to monitor its execution using `pidstat`, but `pidstat` takes a pid and I don't know how to make one send the pid to the other.

I need to monitor disk usage, memory usage, cpu usage and time elapsed. Does any one know of a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In bash (and possibly other shells) you can capture the PID of the last backgrounded process programatically using the `$!` shell variable i.e. it should be possible to do something like

```
dd if=/path/of/file of=/path/of/destination & pidstat -p $!
```

See [this similar askubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/a/402755/178692)

Comment: Thank you for the answers guys, both get the job done but this one its more practical and easier to understand

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by appending a & to the end of your command.

```
dd if=/path/of/file of=/path/of/destination &
```

When you do the above command, it will give you a pid and you can use the pid to monitor.

**Testing**

```
cat infinite.sh
#!/bin/bash
while :
do
        echo "Press [CTRL+C] to stop.."
        sleep 1
done
```

Now, in the first terminal I run the above command as below.

```
-bash-3.2$ ./s.sh &
[1] 25666
-bash-3.2$ Press [CTRL+C] to stop..
Press [CTRL+C] to stop..
Press [CTRL+C] to stop..
Press [CTRL+C] to stop..
```

Now, I can open the second terminal and just use `kill -9 25666` to stop this process. In your case, you can open the second terminal to monitor the `dd` command using the `pid` that you got in the first terminal.